# Links to Contributor Breakdown in stackoverflow documentation

Tags: script, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

A small userscript to insert links to the newly public "Contributor Breakdown" page for SO-Documentation's Topics and Examples.

The script inserts a small hyperlink with text "CB" and title "Contributor Breakdown" at the first available space in the menus available for topics and examples.

[image: Script in action]

#### Installing

As with most userscripts, the script is easiest to use with the browser-extensions Tampermonkey / Greasemonkey

> #### [<kbd>Download / Install</kbd>](https://github.com/Vogel612/mini-se-userscripts/raw/master/documentation-contributor-breakdown.user.js)
>
> <sup>[View source](https://github.com/Vogel612/mini-se-userscripts/blob/master/documentation-contributor-breakdown.user.js) / [GitHub parent repo](https://github.com/Vogel612/mini-se-userscripts)</sup>